How to re-position all the icons in navbar to middle


* {
  padding : 0;
  margin  : 0;
  }
nav {
  padding          : 20px;
  background-color : #809906;
  list-style       : none;
  border-bottom    : 2px solid black;
  }
a {
  color         : black;
  padding-right : 115px;
  }
a:hover {
  color         : hotpink;
  }
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b75e3e30ff.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav>
  <a href="#" style="padding-left: 5px;"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></a>
</nav>



I tried various methods including flexbox to center the icons in navbar but it didn’t work. I am trying to position all the icons to the center of the navbar. I am new in this field.

Flexbox is perfect for navigation bars.


nav {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #809906;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1.5em;
}

a {
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  color: hotpink;
}
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b75e3e30ff.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></a>
</nav>



